# Why are all the DNS names on my network pointing to Amazon AWS?

Tags: dns, ping, local

Whenever I try to access other computers on my network, it fails to connect. If I ping the computer names (for example, "ping fileserver"), it always shows this:

```
Pinging frontend-load-balancer-671953524.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com [204.236.133.222] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I found a new clue. This is my work laptop, so it is on our corporate domain. When I'm at work, "ping fileserver" returns "Ping request could not find host fileserver", which is not unreasonable. So, this DNS problem is either caused by my work domain, or the problem is being hidden by my work domain.

Comment: I had to reinstall Windows on my PC, for other reasons. This problem still happens. I'm completely baffled now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. This only happens on my work laptop. Someone at work set up a DNS alias for "fileserver" that points to Amazon AWS. My laptop is caching that address and trying to use it at home.

I worked around the problem by hard-coding the correct IP address in my hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS server is returning the addresses for Amazon.

What is the IP address of your DNS server?

Is it possible that you are using Amazon's registered addresses on your network behind a NAT and that the DNS is outside the NAT and therefore knows that these are really not your addresses?

Given that you have a DNS server IP address, I think it is safe to assume that the problem is on the device with that address. And since the DNS server is on the router/firewall, I suspect that the problem is that the DNS cache on that device has been poisoned. Try restarting it.

The reason that the other computers don't have a problem is because each computer keeps its own local cache of DNS results for some period of time. So they will not show the problem immediately unless you reboot one of them. The computer with the problem was probably rebooted more recently than the others.

Comment: My DNS server is my wireless router (192.168.11.1). From any other computer, "ping fileserver" returns the correct IP address for that server. From this computer, it gets a completely different IP and the amazonaws.com name.

Comment: The correct IP for "fileserver" is 192.168.11.5. So, it's not an Amazon registered address.

Other than the hosts file, are there any other places in Windows that name resolution can be messed with?

Comment: You may very well have botnet software hijacking your machine and messing with the DNS internally, for instance it may be redirecting all DNS traffic via a network device driver so your Windows config is not relevant

Comment: I just ran scans in Windows Defender and Malwarebytes, and both say my system is clean. Any tips on how to verify that?

Answer (score 0):

If you've checked the hosts file and found nothing, try running the following command in a Command Prompt:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

This will flush the DNS cache.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that; it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem: when I was ping, an Amazon machine answered me.

When I did an nslookup, I realized that the domain suffix was wrong (it was changed by a VPN).

I put in the NIC properties the correct suffix and the problem was solved.